# Profiler Missing

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler

I've enabled the profiler in the admin (`System->Configuration->Developer->Debug->Profiler`) and set it for the individual storefronts for good measure.

I've also enabled the profiler in index.php (`Varien_Profiler::enable();`).

I can get the SQL log to show up, but not the standard profiler.  I've flushed the cache (redis) directly via the CLI, but all I get is the SQL profiler.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?